# Mobile Development Using Only HTML, CSS & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to introduce a class to mobile development.  In the past, the long installation process for using things like phonegap deterred many from completing the assignment, so this time I want to keep things as simple as possible.

My preferred languages are javascript, css, and html.  I know I can create a mobile version of a website using these languages, but that would go through a web browser.  Is it possible to build an app purely using these languages and install it on a phone, with an icon and everything?

Comment: My this answer could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949991/what-is-the-best-way-to-develop-a-website-for-mobile-devices/7950049#7950049

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into jQuery mobile. It's a HTML5 Javascript library for easy app creation: http://jquerymobile.com/ It should be good for students to use for assignments.